# Cannot resolve method openConnection()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download web content from a URL using the code below:

```
URL content = new URL(urlstr);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) content.openConnection();

    try {
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        String existing_string = "";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(existing_string);
        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            builder.append(current);
            data = isw.read();
        }
```

The error I get is `Cannot resolve method openConnection()`. Import statements look like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

I have look at *ALMOST* all SO related questions on this, but I dont seem to get it working.

Comment: Don't forget to import java.net.URL

Comment: When I add `import java.net.URL` android studio wasnt using it.

Comment: `new StringBuilder(existing_string)` is pointless. Just use the no-args constructor. You don't need `existing_string` at all in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have a class of your own called `URL`, possibly this one. Don't do that. Don't use existing JDK class names for your own.

Answer (score 0):

URL content = new URL(urlstr);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) content.chars();

```
try {
    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

    String existing_string = "";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(existing_string);
    int data = isw.read();
    while (data != -1) {
        char current = (char) data;
        builder.append(current);
        data = isw.read();
    }
```

Comment: This problem for simple solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).